Twilio Studio - How I make a http resquest using the widget http request - authorization
friends. I'm developing an IVR using Twilio Studio. Currently, I need to make an HTTP request. Since the APIs are for private use, I first need to go through authorization using my username and password, which generates an access token. How do I authorize myself and then make another request (already having a token)?
What I've done so far: I've created a function that will query the Asset that contains the user and password parameters (json), and then it will make the HTTP request to the endpoint URL in question. However, the error below is presented.
My function
const axios = require('axios');

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    // URL of your asset
    const assetUrl = 'https://authorizationtoken-2014.twil.io/token.json';

    // Make an HTTP request to obtain asset data
    axios.get(assetUrl)
        .then(response => {
            // Check if the response was successful
            if (response.status === 200) {
                // Process the asset data
                const assetData = response.data;
                console.log('Asset data:', assetData);

                // Now you can access the asset information, such as user and password
                const user= assetData.user;
                const password = assetData.password;

                // Check if user credentials are provided
                if (!user|| !password) {
                    return callback("User credentials not provided.");
                }

                // Create the authentication endpoint URL using the asset credentials
                const endpointUrl = `https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/apigateway/token?user=${encodeURIComponent(user)}&password=${encodeURIComponent(password)}`;

                // Make an HTTP request to obtain the access token
                axios.get(endpointUrl)
                    .then(response => {
                        // Check if the response contains the access token
                        const token = response.data.access_token;
                        if (token) {
                            // Access token obtained successfully
                            callback(null, { success: true, token: token });
                        } else {
                            // Access token not found in the API response
                            callback("Access token not found in the API response.");
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        // Error while making HTTP request
                        callback(`Error obtaining access token: ${error}`);
                    });

            } else {
                // Response was not successful
                throw new Error(`Request error: ${response.statusText}`);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // Handle errors while obtaining asset data
            console.error('Error obtaining asset data:', error);
            callback(error);
        });
};


Log Detail
Request URL: https://authorizationtoken-2014.twil.io/authorization
Request Method: POST
Response Status Code: 500
Response Content Type: text/plain


Error
  "function_1": {
      "status_code": 500,
      "content_type": "text/plain",
      "body": "Error: Request failed with status code 403"
    }

"function_1": {
      "status_code": 500,
      "content_type": "text/plain",
      "body": "Access token not found in the API response."


The error suggests that your code is wrong. Can you confirm that it works when you run the code locally or via postman? It's hard to provide help as I can't see the URL endpoint that you try to access.

Hello! I've tested it via Postman. The response works fine.
When you mention URL, are you referring to the same endpoint in question?
https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/apigateway/token?user=${encodeURIComponent(user)}&password=${encodeURIComponent(password)}

yes, your code needs to mimic what postman is doing

Hello, just letting you know that I managed to solve the problem!
